# MySQL Regex in middle of a string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am looking to run an SQL query using a regex match in the middle of a string.

For example, I have a string that is

`Status Changed from Needs Action to Completed`

I want to search where column = `Status Changed from {REGEX} to Completed`

Is this possible at all? I don't know regex too well so am seeking some help

Comment: What is the regexp that you want to match in the middle? Or do you mean that it can be anything in that place?

Comment: `WHERE column LIKE 'Status Changed from % to Completed'`

Comment: You can put parentheses around a pattern in the middle: `WHERE column RLIKE 'Status Changed from (Needs Action|Incomplete) to Completed'`

Comment: is it possible to just match `[a-zA-Z0-9]` ?

Comment: @charlie yes... but put a plus after it like so `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: but how would i use that inside an SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

From your requirement and the comments, it looks like the `LIKE` operator should be pretty close to what you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mycolumn LIKE 'Status Changed from % to Completed'
```

This will allow any sequence of characters as the previous status.

---

Else, if you know in advance the list of possible status values, you can make the filtering more accurate with a regexp:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mycolumn REGEXP 'Status Changed from (Needs Action)|(Open) to Completed'
```

The [`REGEXP` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) checks whether values in the column match the given regular expression. The pipe (`|`) stands for the *alternation* operator (at least one of the value must match).

---

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/PaacquuayZRnmBypC6QgB/1)**

```
create table mytable (
  mycolumn varchar(500)
);

insert into mytable values 
    ('Status Changed from Needs Action to Completed'),
    ('Status Changed from Open to Completed'),
    ('Not a relevant record');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mycolumn LIKE 'Status Changed from % to Completed';

| mycolumn                                      |
| --------------------------------------------- |
| Status Changed from Needs Action to Completed |
| Status Changed from Open to Completed         |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mycolumn REGEXP 'Status Changed from (Needs Action)|(Open) to Completed';

| mycolumn                                      |
| --------------------------------------------- |
| Status Changed from Needs Action to Completed |
| Status Changed from Open to Completed         |
```

Comment: i tried using `'Status Changed from % to Completed'` but it returns no results

Comment: @charlie: this works fine with your sample data though. I added a DB fiddle to my answer for your reference.